# How to set the MaxReceivedMessageSize programmatically when using a WCF Client?

Tags: wcf

I want to set the MaxReceivedMessageSize property to some higher limit (Due to (400) Bad Request error) in my client programmatically.
This is the code I am using...

```
WCFServiceTestClient wcfClient = 
    new WCFServiceTestClient(new wsHttpBinding(), strServiceURL);
```

My service url is dynamic and hence cannot use the web.config.

```
//The following code doesn't seem to take effect
((WSHttpBinding)wcfClient.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding)
        .MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you tried re-ordering the calls so that you set the MaxReceivedMessageSize before instantiating the client? eg,

```
var binding = new wsHttpBinding();
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue; 
var wcfClient = new WCFServiceTestClient(binding, strServiceURL);
```

This may or may not help your 400 error, though.

Comment: Perfect solution saved my day thanks!!!!

Answer (score 11):

I had similar problems in my wcf-service and I solved it with:

```
CustomBinding binding = (CustomBinding)PDAServiceContractClient.CreateDefaultBinding();
            HttpTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
            httpBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            httpBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.Elements.Add(httpBindingElement);

            string address = PDAServiceContractClient.EndpointAddress.Uri.ToString();
            m_proxy = new PDAServiceContractClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(address));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well, though it's not that obvious. It retains all the existing binding properties and only adjusts the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` (which, incidentally, also increases `MaxBufferSize` to the same size).

```
Dim oClient as WcfClient = New WcfClient
CType(oClient.Endpoint.Binding, ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue
```