# WCF service and windows mobile

Tags: wcf, windows-mobile

I have wcf web service which get data and insert it into database.
And I have app which send data to this service.
All work while user send small data set.
but when user send large dataset web service recive error.
How can I set settings for windows mobile which can give me acces to sending large data?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your app symptom, it looks like [the MaxReceivedMessageSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457408/how-to-set-the-maxreceivedmessagesize-programatically-when-using-a-wcf-client) default of 64K is too low. You need to bump it up to an appropriate size. The link above shows how to do it in code but it can also be configured in the application config file in the appropriate binding element.